# ¿Es posible hacer un login con JWT el password en Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Tengo un login de la siguiente forma:

Spring-security.xml

```
<security:http pattern="/login" security="none" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
                            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                         username-parameter="username"
                         password-parameter="password"
                         authentication-failure-url="login?error=true"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccess"
                         authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
                         default-target-url="/inicio"
                         always-use-default-target="false" />

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <security:password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

El me funciona bien... Y todo, ahora lo que quiero es tambien implementar otro como loginToken y sin tener la contraseña, me inicie la sesion en el sistema.

Entonces tener dos inicios de sesion en el archivo de configuración y poder lograr ir o por /login o por /loginToken (en este no viene el password).

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: Lo que hice fue agregar un agregar un: `<security:http pattern="/loginToken" security="none" />` luego de esto, agregar un custom-filter pero no me da el inicio de sesión. @RuslanLópez

Comment: @RuslanLópez Acabo de hacer el mismo proceso del /login con /loginToken pero sin el provider y tampoco...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para responder como solucione el problema que tenia es lo siguiente:

Agrege en un controler un path: /token

Luego en el, agregue una clase "xyz" que me llamara a la clase de userDetailsService y validara si el token es valido.

Entonces simplemente use lo anterior para validar el usuario y ya en la clase de "xyz" valide y levante el contexto: `return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(details, correo, Authorities);`

De esa forma, logre hacer las dos autenticaciones una con user y pass y la otra con token sin impactar la que ya existia...

Ademas de que no era restricción hacerlo de esa manera.